# If a WordPress site were a house, how would you define each component?

Tags: discussion

Several languages comprise a WordPress site. If you were to describe to someone using the analogy of a *house*, how would you describe each of these components?

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. PHP
4. SQL
5. Javascript
6. WordPress

Yes I know WordPress is simply a collection of the other elements, but it is still a component to be considered, optionally.

I had described it to someone as such:

The **HTML** is the structure. The studs and walls. **CSS** is paint, window treatments, carpet, and a well-manicured lawn. **PHP** and **SQL** are water/sewage and electric service delivered to the property. **Javascript** is all the internal plumbing and wiring in the walls. **WordPress** is all of the major (and minor) appliances.

Just kind of a fun discussion here. Got any better analogies?

Comment: ... and we don't want the bugs crawling up the bathtub drain ;-)

Comment: Maybe we should create our own [*always-friday-in-iceland*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/always-friday-in-iceland) tag ;-)

Comment: A better analogy would be a toilet, with the "PHP and SQL" being the "organic" part from it. Yes, it's that bad

Answer (score 1):

- MySQL is the structural frame
- PHP is the in-wall wiring and plumbing
- HTML is the drywall & cabinentry
- CSS is the paint, trim, fixtures, curtains, and upholstry
- Javascript is the appliances, lamps, and devices

Plugins add more built-in functionality to your house, such as central heat or central AC.

Themes are collection of decor elements designed to work well together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to change up what you have listed as the components:

`PHP` is equal to the studs and some of the insulation that keeps the home efficient.

`SQL` is equal to the plumbing and electrical. It goes where you need it to and when you want it thanks to:

`WordPress` is the switches on the wall and anything using plumbing and electricity. The `admin` area would be the basement and or garage where these things can be tinkered with.

**Themes** are a package of `HTML` (the drywall), `CSS` (the paint / wallpaper), and `JavaScript` (the decorations).

Ultimately every piece can be a foundation of one another. It just depends on how you want your house to function. You can build a house, a high-rise, or a Mall. It just depends on how you arrange the components.